# Ansible task not installing the right package

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm specifying `php70u` in my Ansible task. However, `ph71u` seems to get installed instead. I'm trying to figure out why.

Ansible version:

```
me@virtualbox:~/Desktop/ansible_centos$ ansible --version
ansible 2.5.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/me/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Confirming that no PHP packages are currently installed:

```
[me@server ~]$ rpm -qa | grep php
[me@server ~]$
```

Confirming that the IUS repository is installed:

```
[me@server ~]$ sudo yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.its.sfu.ca
 * epel: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: mirror.gpmidi.net
 * ius: ftp.rediris.es
 * updates: mirror.it.ubc.ca
repo id                                                                              repo name
base                                                                                 CentOS-6 - Base
epel                                                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64
extras                                                          
                     CentOS-6 - Extras
ius                                                                                  IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64
updates                                                                              CentOS-6 - Updates
repolist: 20,549
```

Ansible task

```
- name: install PHP7
  yum: name=php70u state=present
```

Ansible error:

```
TASK [php : install PHP7] ******************************************************
fatal: [local_centos6_vm]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error: php71u-common conflicts with php70u-common-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64\n", "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\nSetting up Install Process\nLoading mirror speeds from cached hostfile\n * base: mirror.its.sfu.ca\n * epel: download-ib01.fedoraproject.org\n * extras: mirror.gpmidi.net\n * ius: mirror.slu.cz\n * updates: mirror.it.ubc.ca\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package mod_php70u.x86_64 0:7.0.27-1.ius.centos6 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.27-1.ius.centos6 for package: mod_php70u-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package php70u-common.x86_64 0:7.0.27-1.ius.centos6 will be installed\n--> Processing Conflict: php71u-common-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1.14-1.ius.centos6\n--> Processing Conflict: php71u-common-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 conflicts php70u-common\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem\n You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest\n"]}
```

Then, if I try to see which PHP packages are installed, I get this:

```
[me@server ~]$ rpm -qa | grep php
php71u-common-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php71u-cli-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php71u-xml-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php71u-process-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
```

If I remove all `php71u*` packages, I can reinstall by hand fine:

`sudo yum install php70u`

```
[me@server~]$ rpm -qa | grep php
php70u-common-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
mod_php70u-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
[me@server ~]$
```

**Edit #1**

Using the command module instead of the yum module:

```
- name: install PHP7
  command: yum install php70u
```

Results:

```
TASK [php : install PHP7] ******************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using yum module rather than running yum

fatal: [local_centos6_vm]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["yum", "install", "php70u"], "delta": "0:00:02.861760", "end": "2018-02-27 14:22:45.971565", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-02-27 14:22:43.109805", "stderr": "Error: php71u-common conflicts with php70u-common-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64", "stderr_lines": ["Error: php71u-common conflicts with php70u-common-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64"],
```

**Edit #2**

I decided to add the task to remove PHP71u

```
- name: remove PHP71u
  yum: name=php71u state=absent

- name: install PHP70u
  yum: name=php70u state=present
```

I got the same issue:

```
TASK [php : remove PHP71u] *****************************************************
ok: [local_centos6_vm]

TASK [php : install PHP70u] ****************************************************
fatal: [local_centos6_vm]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error: php71u-common conflicts with php70u-common-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64\n", "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\nSetting up Install Process\nLoading mirror speeds from cached hostfile\n * base: mirror.its.sfu.ca\n * epel: mirrors.lug.mtu.edu\n * extras: mirror.gpmidi.net\n * ius: mirror.slu.cz\n * updates: mirror.it.ubc.ca\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package mod_php70u.x86_64 0:7.0.27-1.ius.centos6 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.27-1.ius.centos6 for package: mod_php70u-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package php70u-common.x86_64 0:7.0.27-1.ius.centos6 will be installed\n--> Processing Conflict: php71u-common-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1.14-1.ius.centos6\n--> Processing Conflict: php71u-common-7.1.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 conflicts php70u-common\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem\n You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest\n"]}
```

**Edit #3**

Once I found the script, I ran it with the explode parameter which generated `debug_dir`. Then, I grepped for `php` and found one line where I find `php70u`:

```
[me@server debug_dir]$ grep -ir ".*php.*"
args:{"ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS": {"_ansible_version": "2.5.0", "_ansible_selinux_special_fs": ["fuse", "nfs", "vboxsf", "ramfs", "9p"], "name": "php70u", "_ansible_module_name": "yum", "_ansible_verbosity": 3, "_ansible_syslog_facility": "LOG_USER", "_ansible_socket": null, "state": "present", "_ansible_diff": false, "_ansible_debug": false, "_ansible_shell_executable": "/bin/sh", "_ansible_check_mode": false, "_ansible_no_log": false}}
```

Here's the content debug files for the removal of the PHP71u:

```
[me@server debug_dir]$ grep -ir php
args:{"ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS": {"_ansible_version": "2.5.0", "_ansible_selinux_special_fs": ["fuse", "nfs", "vboxsf", "ramfs", "9p"], "name": "php71u", "_ansible_module_name": "yum", "_ansible_verbosity": 3, "_ansible_syslog_facility": "LOG_USER", "_ansible_socket": null, "state": "absent", "_ansible_diff": false, "_ansible_debug": false, "_ansible_shell_executable": "/bin/sh", "_ansible_check_mode": false, "_ansible_no_log": false}}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use command and call yum directly from ansible? To see if it is ansible or the yum module

Comment: Same results when I use the command module.

Comment: For what it is worth, this works for me on mac. vagrant init 'geerlingguy/centos6' && vagrant up --provider virtualbox && ansible -b -u vagrant --ssh-extra-args='-p 2222 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=No -oUserKnownHostsFile='dev'null' --private-key .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -m yum --args 'name=https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm state=present update_cache=yes' -i 127.0.0.1, all -v &&

Comment: ansible -b -u vagrant --ssh-extra-args='-p 2222 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=No -oUserKnownHostsFile='dev'null' --private-key .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -m yum --args 'name=php70u state=present update_cache=yes' -i 127.0.0.1, all -v

The two invocations of ansible due to repo need to be installed before php to avoid error of not finding package.

Comment: Would there be a different repository cache between the ansible executable and the destination server?

Comment: Well, since you get the error with the command module as well and the message confirms that the command is correct (ie no jinja yaml parse mischief) and it works on a clean machine, I would be fairly confident that the error is in the state of your target machine rather than ansible. You could set ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOT_FILES envvar and run ansible with -vvv. Ansible will not remove the script it executed on the target then and -vvv will reveal file name. Does it introduce anything behind the scenes of significance?

Comment: I updated my post with edit #3 with the details you requested. Is that the sort of thing you were talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. I was installing pear by itself, part of another task, in a common list of items. This was installing `php71u` before I got to install `php70u`.

I discovered this after commenting out my php role, installing php70u manually and encountering an issue with my common list of items.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that RPM is throwing:

```
Error: php71u-common conflicts with php70u-common-7.0.27-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
```

...implies that `php71u` *is* already installed somehow.

Until you find the underlying reason for this, since you don't want it put a task just before the install to remove it:

```
- name: remove php71u
  yum: name=php71u state=absent
```

Comment: I do run `sudo yum remove php71u*` and confirm with `rpm -qa | grep php` that no PHP is installed prior to running the playbook. Essentially, before I run my playbook, there's no PHP installed. Also, did a grep on my entire Ansible scripts for the string 'PHP' and there's only my php70u task that is found (ie. I'm not installing php71u elsewhere by accident).

Comment: Added the task to remove php71u prior to installing php70u and I'm getting the same results. Very strange.